# Laravel 5.2.45 Where is the Auth Controller and model?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Where are the "out-of-the-box" Authentication Controllers and Models for Laravel 5.2.45? I've searched thoroughly and I keep seeing it's in app/http/auth but only HomeController and a minimal Controller.php is there.

Also, It's a fresh install with only minimal edits such as new files to views and assets such as css and js. I used "php artisan make:auth" and the output only stated the new view files.

I'm learning Laravel to replace Codeigniter and this is a stump I've stumbled upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model files are stored directly inside the `app` directory.
The controller files are stored inside `app/Http/Controllers` directory. Auth Controller is inside `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`.
By the way in the mentioned version of laravel no `HomeController` file is generated by laravel.

Comment: I only have HomeController and a custom controller in my app/Http/Controllers/Auth 

I'm not sure how to properly embed a picture on here but I've linked a picture of my directory.

[LINK](http://i66.tinypic.com/eziruh.jpg)

Comment: As far as I can see those controllers are outside the `Auth` directory and directly inside the `Controllers` directory. Your `AuthController` is inside the `Auth` directory.